# cAdvisor: Reliably get container short name

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I'm using [cadvisor's API](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/api.md) to extract data from a docker machine for monitoring purposes.  I've noticed that for all containers that I've created there's an aliases array in the data which contains a hash and the short name in a specific order (0 seems to always be the short name and 1 seems to always be the unique hash).

```
{
    name: "/docker/4b29315fca60ce0e8e91889f9c8a4f35b6374fbbfcf6a92a108015106dd4ab77",
    aliases: [
        "stupefied_albattani",
        "4b29315fca60ce0e8e91889f9c8a4f35b6374fbbfcf6a92a108015106dd4ab77"
    ]
}
```

Seems is the key word here.  Unfortunately the documentation on cAdvisor's API is almost non-existent so I can't look there for a definitive answer.  The fact that the data is an array named "aliases" seems to imply that it is possible for there to be aliases other than the hash and the short name created for a container.  I also can't be certain that the order will always be 0 = short name, 1 = hash.

Is it safe to assume that aliases[0] is going to always be the short name (provided that aliases array exists), and if not then how can I extract the short name from the data with 100% confidence that I'm getting the correct field?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, unique hash value always comes at `aliases[1]` but it does not imply that `aliases[0]` is always short. As you can see in the following image.[image]